# Is there an iPhone app that will pop a message on another device?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

Is there an iPhone app that will let me pop up a message on another device (iPad / iPhone / iPod)?

For example I would have the app running on both devices and from my iPhone type "come upstairs" and it would pop up a message on the receiving device that shows "come upstairs"

Comment: Yes, it's called text messaging.

Comment: Hi David, can you clarify your question so we know why the messages app isn't suitable for your needs?

Comment: @fbara ----- 

Comment: @Monomeeth it is for a friend who teaches a class and wants to demo something. communication apps don't meet his needs. Maybe nothing exists to do this because of those apps...

Comment: Gave you a good answer, let me know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pushbullet for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pushbullet/id810352052), which is an app designed to let you instantly send messages, files, and links from one device of yours to another.

Pushbullet will let you sign in with one account on all of your iOS, Android, Windows, and macOS devices, and will let you write a message on one device and have it pop up as a notification on any or all of your other devices.